# Change #_content in native joomla module articles category

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to modify a native joomla module that display articles of a category. I want it to display articles of an other prefix tables (both joomla website are ON THE SAME DB).

Notice that I already looked at available extension but none of them would fit.

I did try to modify the router.php by changing the `#__tablename` with `rsc_tablename`

But it did not change anything, the article displayed ar still from the intern tables (ARCS_tables)

---

Ps: there no arsc_tables nor #_tables in the helper.php of the native module

---

Comment: Hi Giom, I forgot to ask last time, why do you have 2 websites connecting to the same database? You do realise this isn't a good idea and will slow things down. i would recommend having 2 separate databases for the sites and then you wont have this problem with the articles ;)

Comment: Hi Lodder, good to see you! Well my host provider give me only a single DB for all website. I did not know about it could slow, makes sense... Well when I ll get more traffic I ll put them in separate tables (need to buy an other db access). Thanks for that advice, have a good day!

Comment: Are you using seperate prefixes for the tables?

Comment: SomeKitten: hello ! Thanks for your reply! Yes  ARCS_ and RSC_ the last one is the external table (same DB)

Comment: Ok I just sent it Lodder (an adventure from a mobile!)

Comment: SomeKitten do you know the trick to modify the native module to access other prefix table?